# How do you include user input in exception message Java?

Tags: java, exception, io, console-application

Is it possible, in Java, to include a user's input into an exception message while also using the valuse as an `int` or `double`? For example, they should enter a number (e.g., 5) but instead fat-finger something like (5r).

Is it possible to have a message say something like "You entered 5r, but should have entered a number."?

I tried using the traditional way of getting variables to print in Java here:

```
try {
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Value: ");
  double value = sc.nextDouble();sc.nextLine();
  exec.ds.push(value);
} 
catch (Exception e1) {
    System.out.println(e1+ "You entered:  " + value + ": You must enter a number");                            
}
```

In this case, I am trying to get `value` displayed in the Exception message, where value is the user's invalid input.

At `value` it gives the error `cannot find symbol`.

Below is the **answer** I came up with. The reason I choose this answer was because most of your answers produced the output, "You entered 0.0 ..." because the answer must first be a string to be printed in the console. In addition, to be used as a number elsewhere in the program the String has cast to an Object of type Double or Integer :

```
String value = null; //declared variable outside of try/catch block and initialize. 
try {
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Value: ");
  value = sc.nextLine(); //Accept String as most of you suggested
  Double newVal = new Double(value); //convert the String to double for use elsewhere
  exec.ds.push(newVal); //doulbe is getting used where it would be a 'number' instead of string

} 
catch (Exception e1) {
    System.out.println(e1+ "You entered:  " + value + ": You must enter a number"); //the String valuse is received and printed as a String here, not a 'number'            
} //now prints what the users inputs...
```

Comment: And what is the problem you are having?

Comment: updated o.p. to show error

Comment: Well, you have a lot of answers to choose from. They all basically say the same thing so you should be all set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not work, because `value` is no longer in scope in the catch block. Instead you can declare it before the try:

```
double value = 0;
try {
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Value: ");
  value = sc.nextDouble();sc.nextLine();
  exec.ds.push(value);
} catch (Exception e1) {
  System.out.println(e1+ "You entered:  " + value + ": You must enter a number");                            
}
```

This will however not help if the exception is thrown because of a syntax error in the double. To handle this, you need to read a `String` and then convert to a `double`.

Answer (score 2):

Get user input:

```
String input = '';

try{

    Console console = System.console();
    input = console.readLine("Enter input:");
}
```

... then in your catch you could do:

```
catch (Exception e1) {
    System.out.println(e1+ "You entered:  " + input + ": You must enter a number");                            
  }
```

Other than the above, I don't see what the problem is. You can google how to get user input in Java, and then just take the input, put it in a variable, and print it out on error.

Answer (score 1):

> value it gives the error cannot find symbol.

You have declare the value in local block. And you are trying to access it outside the block.

> Is it possible to have a message say something like "You entered 5r, but should have entered an number.

Better option is to use flag variable and loop until user enter correct number.

```
boolean flag = true;
double value = 0;
while(flag)
{
    try {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Value: ");
        value = sc.nextDouble();
        exec.ds.push(value);
        flag = false;
    } 
    catch (Exception e1) {
        System.out.println(e1+ "You entered:  " + value + ": You must enter a number");                            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case - no, as the calling of `sc.nextLine()` causes the exception to be thrown, so no value is written to variable `value`.

Moreover, `value` is a local variable in this case and is unavailable from other blocks of code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29) `nextDouble()`:

> Scans the next token of the input as a double. This method will throw `InputMismatchException` if the next token cannot be translated into a valid double value.

So, if the input cannot be translated into a double, an exception is thrown. If you want to provide the inputted string in the exception message, I suggest you read the line as a string and try to parse it to a double, and if that fails, you can include the read line in the exception message.